# Wierd gaps appearing in between SKSpriteNode - swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**Note:** I have tried this answer: [Gap between SKSpriteNodes in SpriteKit collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448536/gap-between-skspritenodes-in-spritekit-collision-detection)

I am getting gaps in between my SKSpriteNodes, after 5 minutes of letting my game run. Here is my code to make the node:

```
let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "world1Tile\(tileNumber).png")
tileNode.position.x = x
tileNode.position.y = y
tileNode.size.width = 128
tileNode.size.height = 128
tileNode.zPosition = 10
tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tileNode.size)
tileNode.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
tileNode.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
tileNode.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
tileNode.name = "Tile"
row.append(tileNode)
```

When I remove the physics body, it is running fine. Here is are some images to show you what I mean:
[image: With physics immediately taken.]

This image has a physics body, and was taken after immediately after running the app.

[image: This image was taken 5 minutes after running the app.]

This image was taken 5 minutes after running the app.

Why is this happening? I assume it has something to do with the physics body, because my app looks exactly like the first picture, even an hour after running the app if there is no physics body. What physics body property should I change to stop this from happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there is no gap. you probably have 'showPhysics' to true in your gameviewcontroller, and the line appears as a gap to me.

compare position with and without the pb to verify.

Comment: `self.view!.showsPhysics = false` solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @KingCoder11 Huzzah! :D

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue not too long ago, where gaps were appearing between nodes that were tiled (although I didn't use physics). Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921017/spritekit-nodes-adjusting-position-a-tiny-bit), I found that if you want perfect alignment between nodes, it is best to ensure that the positions of nodes as well as the nodes' width and height are whole numbers.

I would suggest to round-off the `x` and `y` values of the position of  `tileNode` and see if it will make any difference .

Comment: But why does it run good when the game starts, and why does it only happen after 5 minutes? Anyways, I tried rounding them off, but it didn't make a difference, because they were whole numbers the entire time.

Comment: I had similar problem when gaps started appearing after few minutes. It was caused by position values becoming bigger after some time in infinite scrolling game. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where gaps between sprites started appearing after around 5 minutes of scrolling with constant speed (game with infinite scroll). I did not use physics and I even had all positions, widths, heights rounded to integer value. I was scrolling the camera and adding new sprites one right after another and everything was working fine except after around 5 minutes of that infinite scrolling gaps begin to appear just as in your case. I spent some time in looking for a solution and it turned out that the problem was that when positions of my objects were becoming big that is in my case X position in the scene was around 150000 then those gaps started to appear and also I noticed that this problem occurred only on devices which had to scale the scene. I was using aspect fill with default scene size for iPhone 6 resolution and those gaps only appeared on iPhone 5 but on iPhone 6 I did not notice them. I was able to fix that issue by subtracting some constant value from X position of all objects (including camera position) from time to time so that everything on the scene relatively did not change position to the camera and look the same but actually absolute positions were changed to keep them low. I guess that larger position values like 150000 and scene scaling cause some floating point rounding issue in SpriteKit and that is why gaps are then becoming visible.

So based on my experience if you have similar gaps I recommend using integer values for all positions, widths, heights and additionally keep values of objects positions of all objects low.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference in case someone is still searching for this, here are my experiences:

- If tiles have PhysicsBodies, they are prone to making gaps. A solution for me was making a blank SKNode as a child of the tile, and assigning the PhysicsBody to that.
- If possible, make sure bit masks are set in a way that tiles can't collide with each other.
- As stated in a previous answer, make sure all measurements are integers and rounded in a way that doesn't leave a one unit gap between them.

A related problem is also SpriteKit's PhysicsBody drifting. There are some threads about this (e.g. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27057 ), and it seems to be abug. In my case, the problem was a combination of PhysicsBodies causing random small gaps, and the drifting making some of them larger. The steps above removed the small gaps. Unfortunately the only workaround for the drifting problem in my case was to only generate PhysicsBodies for nodes that are within a certain distance from the player and destroying them after they are left behind.

Comment: I noticed the SKTiled library makes gaps even without physics bodies. SKTiled however doesn't produce real tile sets (using SKTileMapNode), instead, it creates many separate nodes for each tile. Which is probably why tiny gaps sometimes occur during movement.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for anyone who needs, I found an different answer specific to my problem. As JohnV said, I may need to round of values when setting the position, but when running the code, I found out that I also need to do that when running SKActions.